# Ion Auth - Create_User In Another Controller Does Not Work

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I've taken the "auth" controller and copied it and renamed it as "site". I have renamed the references to views etc. to "site". When I go to www.mysite/index.php/site/create_user the form loads fine. However on hitting submit I get redirected to www.mysite.com/index.php/site/login and nothing is added to the database.  Can anyone tell me why this does not work? My site controller is below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

//
//Authentication
//

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library(array('ion_auth','form_validation'));
    $this->load->helper(array('url','language'));

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));

    $this->lang->load('auth');
}


//Function to log the user in       
function login()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Login";

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        // check to see if the user is logging in
        // check for "remember me"
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
        {
            //if the login is successful
            //redirect them back to the home page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            // if the login was un-successful
            // redirect them back to the login page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('site/login', 'refresh'); // use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // the user is not logging in so display the login page
        // set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        $this->data['identity'] = array('name' => 'identity',
            'id'    => 'identity',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
        );
        $this->data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
            'id'   => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
        );

        $this->_render_page('site/login', $this->data);
    }
}

//Function to log the user out
function logout()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

    // log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    // redirect them to the login page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
}


//Function to create a user
function create_user()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Create User";

    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        //redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
    }

    $tables = $this->config->item('tables','ion_auth');

    // validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email|is_unique['.$tables['users'].'.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $username = strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'));
        $email    = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $additional_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
            'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
        );
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
    {
        // check to see if we are creating the user
        // redirect them back to the admin page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect("site", 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        // display the create user form
        // set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

        $this->data['first_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'first_name',
            'id'    => 'first_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
        );
        $this->data['last_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'last_name',
            'id'    => 'last_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
        );
        $this->data['email'] = array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
        );
        $this->data['company'] = array(
            'name'  => 'company',
            'id'    => 'company',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('company'),
        );
        $this->data['phone'] = array(
            'name'  => 'phone',
            'id'    => 'phone',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone'),
        );
        $this->data['password'] = array(
            'name'  => 'password',
            'id'    => 'password',
            'type'  => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
        );
        $this->data['password_confirm'] = array(
            'name'  => 'password_confirm',
            'id'    => 'password_confirm',
            'type'  => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
        );

        $this->_render_page('site/create_user', $this->data);
    }
}


//Function to render the page
function _render_page($view, $data=null, $returnhtml=false)//I think this makes more sense
{

    $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;

    $view_html = $this->load->view($view, $this->viewdata, $returnhtml);

    if ($returnhtml) return $view_html;//This will return html on 3rd argument being true
}
```

}

This exact code works when in the auth controller. When in the site controller I make it so you must login and you must be an admin to make a user (i.e. uncommenting out this line //redirect('site/login', 'refresh');) then it also works, but for some reason when that line is commented it works in the auth controller but not the site controller.

Any help is much appreciated. I've tried to figure it out but can't see why it works in one and not the other (and why it works in site but only as an admin when that code is uncommented and not at all when it is commented, whilst in auth it works in either case).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get redirected is one of two reasons.

First : `$this->_render_page('site/login', $this->data);`

When you hit the submit button it is still pointing to the login controller.

Second : `if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())`

The create user function in the Auth controller is for admins only, You will have to `//` out the code or you will be redirected to the login page due to not being logged and not being an admin.

try this:

`//$this->_render_page('site/login', $this->data);`

`//if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())`

By marking out these two lines you should be able to veiw and submit your page without being redirected.
:)